# determine url is true or false

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I use ASP.NET with javascript ,

I have a question in my code

I need to determine url exists or not

```
url="http://www.404.com"    
If url == exists then
{

}
else if url == not then
{

}
```

Comment: What do you mean, true or false? If it exists or not?

Comment: wat? that made even less sense!

Comment: I predict a question close..............

Comment: Have you looked into using `HttpWebRequest`?

Comment: Or make a jquery $.get() if you can use jQuery and you're okay with asynch calls.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to do it in C# try this out, it will validate any url for you

```
private bool ValidateUrl(string url)
{
    try
    {
        HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(url) as HttpWebRequest;
        request.Method = "HEAD";
        HttpWebResponse response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;
        return (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK);
    }
    catch
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use C# Ping and PingReply classes.

```
private bool ValidateUrl(string url)
{
    try
    {
        Ping x = new Ping();
        int timeout=500;
        PingReply reply = x.Send(url,timeout); 
        if(reply.Status == IPStatus.Success)
          {
              return true;
          }
        else
          {
              return false;
          }
    }
    catch
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Ping works with IPAddresses or hostnames, not with urls. Additionally it's very likely that the ping service is not running on the target machine.